# How do I add translations for alien languages to my app?

Tags: android, localization, google-play

Today, *april 1*, [Google announced they will be adding support for distributing apps in space](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2016/03/get-your-apps-and-games-ready-for-space.html).

I have an app I would like to translate to [Klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon) and [Goa'uld language](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Goa'uld_language). What language codes should I use in my resources?

Or are there any good open source [Universal Translator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_translator) or [Babel Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Babel_fish) library projects I can use in my app?

Answer (score 0):

If you search in locale ?

[image]

Or using Code Country[image]